# Custom UIView in Custom UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiview, uitableview

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` subclassed as `ItemDetailCell` which has many outlets connected to my storyboard file. Among them is a custom `UIView` subclassed as `PriorityView` which has one outlet to a `UIView` (priorityStatusView) in a nib file.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet PriorityView *redPriorityView;
```

In the nib file (PriorityView.xib) I have connected the File's Owner Custom Class to PriorityView. In `PriorityView.m` I am loading the nib file in `drawRect` using:

```
NSArray *array = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PriorityView" owner:self options:nil];
[self addSubview:[array objectAtIndex:0]];
```

In my table view controller's `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I am trying to set the background color of `redPriorityView.priorityStatusView`, but first I am calling `drawRect` so the nib is loaded. The reason I am not using `initWithFrame` to load the nib is that it seems to nullify the `PriorityView` in addition to not loading the nib. My suspicion is this is happening because the view is already being loaded with the `IBOutlet`. I know it is null because I have called:

```
NSLog(@"%@, %@", detailCell.redPriorityView, detailCell.redPriorityView.priorityStatusView);
```

and both return null. However, using `drawRect` to load the nib does return both logs to be not null. The only problem I am having right now is that the background color will not change using:

```
detailCell.redPriorityView.priorityStatusView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
```

I have also tried using `setBackgroundColor` to no avail. Actually, none of the properties of the `redPriorityView` or `redPriorityView.priorityStatusView` seem to change for me. The background color is just an example.

Sorry to make it so long, I am just having a hard time making this work. Thanks in advance for any help!

**Edit**

I have tried setting the properties of the `redPriorityView` using a method in `ItemDetailCell` and calling it via `cellForRowAtIndexPath` but even though the `NSLog` in the method is called the properties don't change. I think the problem may be in how the views are connected to the `PriorityView` file.

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what you're doing here, but using drawRect is not the way to go. For things coming out of a nib, you want to use initWithCoder rather than initWithFrame. A more basic question is, why are you using a separate nib file for priorityStatusView instead of creating it inside your ItemDetailCell in the first place?

Comment: @rdelmar I am using the view three times in the detailCell. When final it will have a subview and tap gesture recognizer so I thought it'd be easier to control all the functionality of the `UIView` if I subclassed it.

Comment: @rdelmar Additionally, it is not possible to add gesture recognizers to prototype cells. So using a custom view seems to be my only choice.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method, and try setting the background color in it. Hope this helps!

Comment: Why use this instead of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: I just tried using that but it doesn't make any difference, unfortunately.

Comment: "A table view sends this message to its delegate just before it uses cell to draw a row, thereby permitting the delegate to customize the cell object before it is displayed. This method gives the delegate a chance to override state-based properties set earlier by the table view, such as selection and background color."

Answer (score 0):

try setting your accessors to strong. Maybe...